# Android : Step for Android connect to Laravel API

Tags: java, php, android, laravel

I am new in programming. And I would like to ask what is the step to **connect Laravel API**. Let say I want to build an **Android App** and I want to connect to the **backend** that is **Laravel** but the point is, the backend is not created by me it is created by other developer and I'm totally don't understand in PHP.

So in this situation, what is the step or how to do Android connect with the Laravel?

**PS**: I have already saw some sample from other article, but the tutorial mostly are build the both Laravel and Android at the same time. So that is quite not same with my situation...

So Hope I can find out the answer from here. Thanks in advance

Comment: There's no difference between a API created in Laravel and any other kind of API. To connect (or make requests) to the API i would recommend you to take a look at Retrofit library

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden, Ya I think is a custom API created with Laravel. So sorry for my question, because I'm not very understand in PHP...

Comment: @Vixo, Alright, I will have a look to this and thanks for your comment. By the way, do you know any clearly step for Android connect to API tutorial? And better its similar with my situation.

Comment: @Desmond I find the official guide really good: [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) but I'm sure you can find some more beginner-friendly somewhere else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Retrofit for creating calling API service in your android application.
This is a very good tutorial: https://www.journaldev.com/13639/retrofit-android-example-tutorial.

For Laravel API, you can follow tutorial: https://www.toptal.com/laravel/restful-laravel-api-tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

The very first step to interacting with a remote REST API is to have an understanding of what the expected request and response data is. This can typically be found in the documentation of the REST API you're trying to access. In this case, since it has been created by another developer, you should ask them for the docs.

After you've gotten a decent understanding of the API, you can use one of several HTTP client libraries for Android such as [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) to send requests and receive responses from the API.

> **Note**: It is not necessary to understand the API's code, only the REST endpoints and the request/response schema. A good example of API documentation can be found [here](http://editor.swagger.io/)